# get last in LINQ list

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
Context db = new Context();
List<Invoice> invoice =
(from LocalInvoice in db.Invoices
where LocalInvoice.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier
select LocalInvoice).ToList();
```

Returns a list of records. I want to select the last in the list.
I've tried `.ToList().LastOrDefault();`
but the error im getting is cannot convert type 'invoice' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List.

Why is it saying this have I not declared invoice as a list `List<Invoice> invoice`

Any help much appreciated.
Ta

---

**EDIT**
Thanks for the reply everyone i've tried what you all have advised and each time im getting the error: The query operator 'LastOrDefault' is not supported.

**Also** I havent actually explained what I am trying to do overall which may be causing a problem.
I have a table containing all the invoices, each with a seperate 'id'. However each record will have a SiteIdentifier column which is used multiple times for different invoices.
So each Site may have multiple invoices.

Trying to get the most recent Invoice for the site.
So say invoice

```
id SiteIdentifier 
73 25
74 25
75 25
```

I was attempting to get all the records where the SiteIdentifier == this.SiteIdentifier(e.g.25), then get the most recent record which would have beeing invoice id 75.

Anyone have any ideas?
Again thanks for all the help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

LastOrDefault will return a single element. You shouldn't call ToList without applying a filter first, it would retrieve all the rows from the database while you just need one.

```
var invoice = db.Invoices.LastOrDefault(s => s.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier);
```

Also you have to apply ordering if you are querying a relational table. LastOrDefault is only meaningful with in-memory collections. Looks like it is not supported in EF and will throw an exception.

Best solution is to inverse the ordering and use FirstOrDefault method:

```
var invoice = db.Invoices.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id) 
                         .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier);
```

Comment: the second example works but ONLY for first or default. im afraid i specifically need the most recent record in the DB.  .last is throwing an error The query operator 'Last' is not supported., and lastordefault is the same as the original error in my original post. Have you any ideas?

Comment: @John That's why you are ordering in the first place. I assumed that the record with the biggest Id would be the most recent one. Remote sequences don't act like in-memory ones, it has no way of deciding which one is last unless you tell it how. That's why LastOrDefault is not supported, you have to use FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 5):

LastOrDefault will return an instance of an Invoice, not a collection, so change the variable type.

```
Invoice invoice =
   (from LocalInvoice in db.Invoices
    where LocalInvoice.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier
    select LocalInvoice).LastOrDefault();
```

or cleaner still:

```
var invoice = db.Invoices.LastOrDefault(i => i.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`LastOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) will return a single element, not a `List`. This would work:

```
Invoice invoice =
    (from LocalInvoice in db.Invoices
     where LocalInvoice.Site_Id == this.SiteIdentifier
     select LocalInvoice)
    .LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Really inefficient! Will query database for all records and take last on application, not on database side.